# Вопрос по NSDateFormatter:

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [­[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; 
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSDate *createDate = self.event.createdDate;

NSLog(@"%@", createDate);
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:createDate]);
```

Первый NSLog распечатывает дату корректно (2014-09-04T19:02:40.000Z).

Второй NSLog всегда (null).
Никак не могу понять, почему так происходит, есть идеи?

Comment: А где у Вас находится второй NSLog? В той же границе видимости?

Comment: в одной,прям под первым nslog'ом
как только добавляю дату в форматер сразу получаю null

Comment: Добавьте в пример второй вызов NSLog именно так, как это у вас в коде, без сокращений.
___


Вы от нас что-то скрываете. Приведенный код работает, если вызовы NSLog расположены так, как Вы указали. Скиньте этот файл, в котором вы это делаете, на файл-хостинг и дайте сюда ссылку.

Comment: если создаю nsdate *date = [nsdate date];
и в нслог ставлю date - все работает

дело в self.event.createdDate - это nsdate из json,скорее всего надо как то через строку делать
на какой файл-хостинг лучше скинуть?

Comment: На любой. Давайте на Dropbox-Google Drive.